# Transforming Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure what would be the best way to approach transforming this JS Array.

I have an array with a structure like (could contain more than 1 element):

```
let arr1 = [{amount: '10', quantity: 2, id: '123'}, {....}]
```

but I need to take that and transform that into an array structured like

```
let arr2 = [{value: '10'}, {value: '10'}]
```

Essentially adding new objects into the array based on the quantity in array 1.

I was thinking basic for loop but it seems to be getting a bit messy. Is there a simple way in JS to do this? Either with some sort of built in function etc?

Comment: Do you want the new array to be tracked by `id`? and `arr1` can have more than 1 element I'm assuming?

Comment: So I'm not bothered about tracking the id really. It's a little bit of redundant information.

Yes in theory arr1 could contain more than 1 element

Comment: Please read [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @jabaa If you re-read my question it tells you I've been using a for loop and it's become messy. So I have tried something. I didn't post anything specific in here because I couldn't come up with a viable solution. This is why I asked a generalised question.

Comment: The tour tells you to show your work (with exclamation mark). Questions without serious approach are off topic. If you don't know how to even start this is probably not the right platform for your question.

Comment: @jabaa Not sure if you're wilfully ignoring my comments or not. I said in my comment, I didn't have a solution to show. I have talked about what solutions I tried (basic for loop etc). There wasn't any code to show because I didn't get it working.

Just to let you know I've reported your comment. It's rude and unnecessary. I didn't ask for people to write code for me (although some kindly did). I asked what was the most optimal solution e.g. `map`, `reduce` etc. So I wasn't asking for code to be written for me.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and that's the reason your question is off topic for Stack Overflow. If you can't show your approach you have to do more research effort or ask somewhere else. Read the [tour] _"Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Which comment (or which part of my comment) is rude? I'm just telling you that this question doesn't fulfill the requirements, posted the links and copied the exact paragraph. IMHO this is necessary to keep the high quality of this platform. If constructive critics is already rude for you you shouldn't post on a public website.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get the result using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

First, you can create a temp array with the number of elements as `quantity` then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the temp array to get the object with property `amount` in it.

```js
let arr1 = [
  { amount: "10", quantity: 2, id: "123" },
  { amount: "30", quantity: 5, id: "123" },
];

const result = arr1.flatMap((obj) => {
  const { amount, quantity } = obj;
  return Array(quantity)
    .fill(0)
    .map((x) => ({ amount }));
});

console.log(result);
```

You can also make the above snippet succinct

```
const result = arr1.flatMap(({ quantity, amount }) => Array(quantity).fill(0).map((x) => ({ amount })));
```

```js
let arr1 = [
  { amount: "10", quantity: 2, id: "123" },
  { amount: "30", quantity: 5, id: "123" },
];

const result = arr1.flatMap(({ quantity, amount }) =>
  Array(quantity)
    .fill(0)
    .map((x) => ({ amount }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using `reduce`, with a manual for loop to append the correct number of entries.

```
let arr1 = [{amount: '10', quantity: 2, id: '123'}];

const result = arr1.reduce((accum, v) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < v.quantity; i++) {
        accum.push({value: v.amount});
    }
    return accum;
} , []);
```

This might have a slight performance improvement over `flatMap`, as it does not create any temporaries.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking basic for loop but it seems to be getting a bit messy

You just need a simple `for` and a `while` loop:

```js
const input = [{amount: '10', quantity: 2, id: '123'}],
      output = []
      
for (let { amount, quantity } of input)
  while (quantity--)
    output.push({ value: amount })

console.log(output)
```

---

You could create `o.quantity` number of objects using `Array.from()`. Use `flatMap` to get a flat array for each item in the input array

```js
const output = input.flatMap(o => 
  Array.from({ length: o.quantity }, _ => ({ value: o.amount }) )
)
```